# urllib's urlencode returning weird encoded results

Tags: python, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, urlencode

I'm trying to use Facebook's REST api, and am encoding a JSON string/dictionary using [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode). The result I get however, is different from the correct encoded result (as displayed by pasting the dictionary in the attachment field here http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/stream.publish/). I was wondering if anyone could offer any help.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I'm trying to encode the following dictionary:

```
{"media": [{"type":"flash", "swfsrc":"http://shopperspoll.webfactional.com/media/flashFile.swf", "height": '100', "width": '100', "expanded_width":"160", "expanded_height":"120", "imgsrc":"http://shopperspoll.webfactional.com/media/laptop1.jpg"}]}
```

This is the encoded string using urllib.urlencode:

`"media=%5B%7B%27swfsrc%27%3A+%27http%3A%2F%2Fshopperspoll.webfactional.com%2Fmedia%2FflashFile.swf%27%2C+%27height%27%3A+%27100%27%2C+%27width%27%3A+%27100%27%2C+%27expanded_width%27%3A+%27160%27%2C+%27imgsrc%27%3A+%27http%3A%2F%2Fshopperspoll.webfactional.com%2Fmedia%2Flaptop1.jpg%27%2C+%27expanded_height%27%3A+%27120%27%2C+%27type%27%3A+%27flash%27%7D%5D`"

It's not letting me copy the result being thrown out from the facebook rest documentation link, but on copying the above dictionary in the attachment field, the result is different.

Comment: Just a deprecation note: "We are in the process of deprecating the REST API, so if you are building a new application you shouldn't use this function. Instead use the Graph API and POST a Post object to the feed connection of the User object."

Comment: Could you provide an example of input/output that behaves unexpectedly?

Comment: @miku: The result returned by the link I posted works though (I'm using REST over graph as graph doesn't allow the specification of height while posting flash files). The only problem I'm running into is I'm not able to encode my attachments properly.Thanks for your comment though :)

Comment: @jeremy: sure, I'll edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`urllib.encode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) isn't meant for urlencoding a single value (as functions of the same name are in many languages), but for encoding a dict of separate values. For example, if I had the dict `{"a": 1, "b": 2}` it would produce the string `"a=1&b=2"`.

First, you want to encode your dict as JSON.

```
data = {"media": [{"type":"flash", "swfsrc":"http://shopperspoll.webfactional.com/media/flashFile.swf", "height": '100', "width": '100', "expanded_width":"160", "expanded_height":"120", "imgsrc":"http://shopperspoll.webfactional.com/media/laptop1.jpg"}]}

import json
json_encoded = json.dumps(data)
```

You can then either use [`urllib.encode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) to create a complete query string

```
import urllib
urllib.encode({"access_token": example, "attachment": json_encoded})
# produces a long string in the form "access_token=...&attachment=..."
```

or use [`urllib.quote`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) to just encode your attachment parameter

```
urllib.quote(json_encoded)
# produces just the part following "&attachment="
```